# Tkinter .icursor(*arg) strange behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, tkinter, cursor

I'd like to create an Entry with Tkinter where the user can type its telephone number and the text dynamically changes in order that once finished it becomes like `+34 1234567890`.

In my code the function `.icursor(n)`, used to set the cursor position, at first does not work properly, but then, surpassed the prefix, it does.

This is my code snippet (It belongs to a much larger one).

```
from Tkinter import *

def TelephoneCheck(self,Vari):
    Plain = Vari.get()
    Plain = list(Plain)

    Plain_flat = []
    for element in Plain:
        try:
            check = int(element)
            Plain_flat.append(element)
        except: pass

    if len(Plain_flat) > 2:
        Plain_flat.insert(2,' ')

    Plain = ''.join(Plain_flat)
    Plain = '+'+Plain

    self.istn.set(Plain)

    self.InsertTelephoneNumber.icursor(len(Plain))



def CreateInsertTelephoneNumber(self,X,Y,color='white'):
    self.istn = StringVar()
    self.istn.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode, istn=self.istn: self.TelephoneCheck(istn))
    self.InsertTelephoneNumber = Entry(Body,textvariable=self.istn)
    self.InsertTelephoneNumber.config(bg=color)
    self.InsertTelephoneNumber.place(height=20,width=230,y=Y+27,x=X+245)



def LabelBody(self,X,Y):
    TelephoneText = Label(Body,text='Telephone Number *')
    TelephoneText.place(y=Y+4,x=X+243)
    self.CreateInsertTelephoneNumber(X,Y)
```

As you see, theoretically, the position should be setted at the end of the string everytime the user adds a number.
I can not understand why it works like a charm only after the prefix and not when the first number is typed (It results as `+(Cursor here)3` instead of `+3(Cursor here)`).

If more code is needed I will update the post.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: "does not work properly" doesn't make sense. What are you getting and not getting exactly?

Comment: @ParvizKarimli .icursor(position) should move the cursor to the specified position. Sadly, it doesn't when the first character is typed. So I'd say that it is a "Does not work properly" behaviour ...

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you printed out the values of variables in order to verify your assumptions?

Comment: @BryanOakley I did. I printed the whole list and its length each time a character was added to the string. I even added a print within the if block and the try-except to see if something was not working, but everything seems ok.

Comment: @MarkZampedroni What I meant was "does not work properly" is too broad, you should specify your problem more accurately. Could you please show us the whole program? I would recommend you to paste a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) link here.

Comment: @ParvizKarimli There you have. Thank you for the suggestion. http://pastebin.com/CCRsfuSm

Comment: @MarkZampedroni Nice job there!

Comment: @MarkZampedroni I'm just amazed -- have you written the validation functionality for `Entry` widgets from scratch??? Because I couldn't see any validate function in your code.

Comment: @ParvizKarimli I think you may call it like that. I don't really know how it's commonly done but I found my own way. Maybe wrong and ugly, but it works... and for me it's enough.

Comment: @MarkZampedroni Sei davvero bravo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the cursor, but then the underlying widget sets the cursor the way it normally does. Because you're inserting characters into the widget in the middle of Tkinter processing a key press and release, it gets confused. For example, on the very first keystroke it thinks the cursor should be at position 1, but you've inserted a character after that position so the cursor ends up between characters.

The simplest solution is to schedule your change to happen after the default behavior by using `after_idle`:

```
Body.after_idle(self.InsertTelephoneNumber.icursor, len(Plain))
```